# sigma.js How to plug a plugin on my own page

Tags: javascript, plugins, drag, sigma.js

I'm totally new at coding and i have some trouble using the dragNodes plugin. I can make the plugin work by itself with the generated random graph example, but I am struggling to make it work with my own graph.

I don't understand what to put in the html. I tried to put only that:

```
`<script src="sigma.js/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js"></script>sigma.plugins.dragNodes(s, s.renderers[0]);`
```

and it doesn't make my nodes move. I think I have to change the content of "s" and "s.renderers[0]" but I cannot find where., and I don't know how to do it...

Basically, I would love if anyone could give me some explanations about how to plug a plugin in my page?
If you could help me, I'm lost and that would be awesome! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up two things:

- How to use script into html
- How to include external js files in a web page.

In order to insert javascript directly into an html page you have to use the `script` tag as follow (called inline js):

```
<body>
    <script>
        // some inline js
        var a = 1;
    </script>
</body>
```

In order to include js from an external file you have to reference the file with the src attribute just like you did.

```
<script src="sigma.js/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js"></script>
```

The only thing that you missed is that `sigma.plugins.dragNodes(s, s.renderers[0]);` is also some js code, you thus have to put it into script tags to that it can be interpreted as such by the browser.

Here is what you probably are trying to write:

```
<script src="sigma.js/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js">
</script>
<script>
    sigma.plugins.dragNodes(s, s.renderers[0]);
</script>
```

Having all this into `<body>`tags.

I should also mention that to render your graph using sigma you should have an instance of sigma in your page, and in your case it should be called `s`.

To learn more about js/web programming I would advise this: http://www.codecademy.com/

As far as documentation for sigma is concerned check out their tutorial: http://sigmajs.org/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nicolas Joseph's answer (put javascript in script tag), you should also download the js library that is required and save the html file in the appropriate path.

For example if your file.html is in a directory dir (dir/file/.html)
Then the command:

```
<script src="sigma.js/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js">
</script>
```

will search for a file named sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js in the following path: 
dir/sigma.js/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js

To check out which librarires you are missing you should open debug mode in your browser (right click->inspect element) and check the console tab.

Cheers